# Share singleton between middleware, controllers and background services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was to put some data into a collection in my middleware. I want to view this data through a controller. And I want to reduce amount of data in this collection through a background service.

In `ConfigureServices()`, I map a Singleton that I want to share with controllers, background services and middleware. For example:

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> sharedData = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ConcurrentQueue<string>), sharedData);
```

This singleton gets injected into my controllers and background services just fine. Does anyone know how I can access this singleton from my middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middleware context has the `IServiceProvider` property `RequestServices`.

e.g.

```
var queue = context.RequestServices.GetService<ConcurrentQueue<string>>();
```

Also, as Tseng pointed out, middleware can have constructor dependency injection when using factory-based method implementing the `IMiddleware` interface.

e.g.

```
public class ConcurrentQueueMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _queue;

    public ConcurrentQueueMiddleware(ConcurrenQueue<string> queue)
    {
        _queue = queue;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // do stuff with your queue

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

More information can be found in the official Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Singletons can also be injected into the middlewares constructor (for statics only) & on the invoke method